# Upload project success but in iTunes connect still shows "waiting for upload"

Tags: xcode, loader

My xcode version is 4.3. I successfully uploaded my project and Organizer-Archives says:No issues was found in "xxx". "xxx" has passed validation and may be submitted to the App Store.
But in iTunes Connect, the project state still shows "waiting for upload".
I reupload it ，but the state  still show "waiting for upload".

Is this an error with Apple's servers or with the Application loader?

Comment: Did you choose Validate or Submit? I think that is the reply when you choose Validate (although I'm not entirely sure).

Comment: Yes. Organizer-Archives says:No issues was found in "xxx". "xxx" has passed validation and maybe submitted to the App Store.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but I meant which button did you click: the Validate button or the Submit button? You must click the Submit button for the status to change from "Waiting for Upload" to "Upload Received" (then eventually "Waiting for Review).

Comment: You meant is enter iTunes connect then entry in to Project detail page then click "submit"?

Comment: I mean in Organizer > Archives.

Comment: I do that。
Before Xcode4.3  I uploaded successfully to a number of the app.
I also understand the basic situation of the xcode upload app. But the last two months I have not uploaded, maybe there is little change?

Comment: Thank you @neilvillareal. It Should look like this:Organizer->Archives->Destribete->Submit to App store

Comment: Good to hear you found it. I admit I can't think of any other reason/way/step, as I used Organizer > Archives > Submit before. But yeah, that was using Xcode 4.2. Thanks also for sharing the steps for Xcode 4.3. =)

Answer (score 0):

While uploading app to app store if your xcode stops because of any reason.
And itunes store status for app is - upload receive, but in xcode organizer status for archive is not submitted.
Then you may face any problem. 
So take care that

1- Staus on app store is - Upload received and 
2- In organise - Submitted.

Then there is no issue.